# Local acyclicity with respect to a sheaf

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

I am trying to understand the definition 2.12 in SGA 4.5, chapter 7. The multitute of localizations confuses me, as I still do not understand very basic algebraic geometric notions.

To get some understanding, I tried to prove the following:

If $X\xrightarrow[]{id} X$ is locally acyclic with respect to $\mathcal{F}$, then $\mathcal{F}$ is locally constant.

Is this true? If yes, could you provide an explicit proof to help me?

Comment: When $\mathcal F$ is a constructible sheaf, this follows by SGA 4 IX 2.11 as the property that the identity map is locally acyclic implies that all the specialization morphisms are isomorphisms.